# Jquery code for color coding in sharepoint 2010

Tags: jquery

I need to do color coding to my sharepoint 2010 calendar. The color coding to be picked up from the lookup column "Event Type" where I have 5-6 values which are dropdown. Could any one please help to provide jquery code for complete color coding in sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I solved it without script. Solution is little bit non-engineer as I didn't have time to spend it searching for better solution but it works :)

There are two columns, one that is drop down choices, which is hidden from View and one multiline text NOTE: rich content checked so you can enter HTML.
the second column is hidden from content type but is visible in View.

Then I created WF in designer like this:
If chosen Option 1 from drop down, use function set field to value, and put HTML code to multiline column.
If option 2 is chosen, again put different HTML code.
HTML code I got like this, I opened new item wrote text I wanted to be shown (It was same text from option 1 from drop down menu) and colored it to color I needed. Then I bluemark that text and clicked on edit source at Format text tab.